# Time Compexity of a loop algorithm

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I am working on time complexity. I have read some books, but still I think I can only understand basic staff. I have a 4 stage loop as an example and I am trying to calculate time complexity for it.

```
for(n=0;n<10000;n++)
    for(i=n; i>0; i=i/2)
        for(j=1; j<i; j=j*2)
            for(k=n;k--;)
```

So starting from the inner part of the loop I am sure that it will be executed `n-1 times`. Also the outer part is also n times..
But can't figure out the other 2 loops complexity and how I will calculate the total. To be more specific, I suspect that they have a logn complexity, but I really think I get it wrong..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: I have read this, and other posts, but still get confused with all of this.. Sorry, I am new at this topic!